# INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED

Tags: android

I tried everything, renaming the package, changing the permissions etc, still i see the error INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED on my console.

I tried logging from logcat and this is what it says is "Failed parse during installPackageLI" and "android.content.pm.PackageParser$PackageParserException: /data/app/vmdl170122893.tmp/base.apk (at Binary XML file line #33):  does not have valid android:name" and atlast says "Debugger is no longer active"

I am trying this to run on em21 ie Lollipop SDK.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="Ca.Rushabh.Mobileproject"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<permission
    android:name="com.example.mymapsv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.example.mymapsv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/blue_droid"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="Ca.Rushabh.Mobileproject.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="Ca.Rushabh.Mobileproject.About"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_about"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="Ca.Rushabh.Mobileproject.ToDoList"
        android:label="abcd" />
    <activity
        android:name="Ca.Rushabh.Mobileproject.ToDoDetailActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize" />

    <provider
        android:name="Ca.Rushabh.Mobileproject.MyToDoContentProvider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:authorities="com.example.mobileproject.todos.contentprovider" />

    <activity
        android:name="Ca.Rushabh.Mobileproject.ViewAnimationActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_animation" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="Ca.Rushabh.Mobileproject.ViewAnimation2"
        android:label="@string/title_animation" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="Ca.Rushabh.Mobileproject.ContactUs"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_contact_us"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="Ca.Rushabh.Mobileproject.GoogleMapV2"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_google_map_v2" >
    </activity>
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" />
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: You might want to use proper case (ie lowercase) for package name

Comment: Package names should always be in lowercase, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12534302/why-java-package-name-should-be-in-lowercase

Comment: I edited to remove you google map api key, beware before posting such data

Comment: i already had lowercase, i saw many discussions with same thing renaming to uppercase (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16015033/installation-error-install-parse-failed-manifest-malformed) and still doesnt work

Comment: @RolfSmit go for it, you did search for a reference

Comment: @RushabhShah replace all package name to lower case then post your logback if it's still failing (and point us to the line of the manifest shown in the error message: `Binary XML file line #33`)

Comment: @RushabhShah it seems the only way to fix this problem is by removing the uppercase package names. What does not work after changing it to lowercase?

Comment: Failed parse during installPackageLI

Comment: android.content.pm.PackageParser$PackageParserException: /data/app/vmdl1812012324.tmp/base.apk (at Binary XML file line #77): <meta-data> requires an android:value or android:resource attribute

Comment: Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed 4485(323KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 19% free, 6MB/8MB, paused 1.271ms total 21.670ms - Shutting Down VM

Comment: This is all after i change the name to lowercase !!

Comment: What don't you understand in "<meta-data> requires an android:value or android:resource attribute" (ie. both meta-data in your manifest need a android:value or android:resource attribute, that's pretty clear IMHO, ieie `com.google.android.gms.version` need a value)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is more than one problem as [RC.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/180100/rc) and I found out.

- Change all your package names to lowercase
- Update the `<meta-data>` attribute to have a valid value.

Correct code for the meta data:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Sources:

- [Google Play Services v13 error meta-data in AndroidManifest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19735507/google-play-services-v13-error-meta-data-in-androidmanifest)
- [Why should java package name be lowercase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12534302/why-java-package-name-should-be-in-lowercase)

Comment: "Change all your package names to lowercase" works for me. Thank you :)

Comment: Oh! man  working on  Kotlin Multiplatform project spent many hours finding the solution. Service was not working in lower apis. Just changed the package name to lower case and worked. Thank you!!

Answer (score 57):

If anyone getting this error on Android 12 (Android S) preview version. Update all of your dependencies to latest one and
Please add -

```
android:exported="true"
```

to to any `<activity>`, `<activity-alias>`,`<service>`, or `<receiver>` components that have `<intent-filter>`s declared in the app’s AndroidManifest.xml file.

Refer to this [link](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/lets-be-explicit-about-our-intent-filters-c5dbe2dbdce0) and [behavioral changes for Android 12 API 31](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#exported).

Comment: @or_dvir Are you trying on Android 12 phone or emulator?

Comment: not working for me, using it on emulator... also what about the manifest files of the external libs? they might not be using exported, will it affect my app?

Comment: using an emulator.
@tronku turns out that was the issue with me IN ADDITION to setting `exported=true`. i updated all my dependencies and that fixed it. but i guess that would not work if the dependencies still did not comply with this new rule. also note that i did not get the specific error message that other people get (telling exactly where the problem is)

Comment: @or_dvir I tried updating the cached manifests of external libs and checked the merged manifest for the exported issue, but found nothing.. still not able to install the app on emulator

Comment: for me, i had to update leakcanary to version 2.9.1 (`debugImplementation "com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:2.9.1"`) because the older version i was using probably didn't have an `exported` attribute

Answer (score 4):

I was getting this issue

```
failed to install c:\users\nisha jain\documents\grayopus 
project\rxsmile\build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk: failure 
[install_parse_failed_manifest_malformed: failed parse during 
installpackageli: /data/app/vmdl914617141.tmp/base.apk (at binary xml file 
line #27): com.grayopus.rxsmile.mainactivity: targeting s+ (version 31 and 
above) requires that an explicit value for android:exported be defined when 
intent filters are present] error launching application on sm e625f.
```

But it was solved by adding this line in AndroidManifest.xml

```
android:exported="true"
```

Answer (score 2):

> INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED: Failed parse during
> installPackageLI: /data/app/vmdl192287100.tmp/base.apk (at Binary XML
> file line #264): com.razorpay.RzpTokenReceiver: Targeting S+ (version
> 31 and above) requires that an explicit value for android:exported be
> defined when intent filters are present'

I tried some different methods but it only worked when I changed `compilesdk` and `targetsdk` from 31 to 30 as follows:

```
compileSdkVersion 30
minSdkVersion 26
targetSdkVersion 30
```

Comment: That is not proper solution. I face same error.

Answer (score 1):

Your package name has a capital letter in it. Try refactoring your package so that all the letters are lowercase. To do this, in the panel for your project, make sure you're in Android view mode, then click the gear that is a little to the right of the view indicator, then make sure compact empty middle packages is unchecked. Next, right click on your package with a capital letter in it and select refactor -> rename. Change it to have a lower case, double check your AndroidManifest.xml is now a lower case, if not, manually edit it.

Comment: Is it okay to use **underscore _** in package name.

Answer (score 1):

none of the proposed solutions worked for me, so im posting this additional answer in the hope it will help others.

what worked for me was setting `exported` value for all my activities (as suggested by @karanatwal.github.io) AND updating all my dependencies, which apparently did not have this value set.

i originally dismissed the dependencies part from my attempts to fix this, as during my research ive seen (online) very specific error messages saying that this is indeed the problem (setting `exported` value) as well as indicating exactly which dependency was not complying with it. for some reason, i did not get this message.

note that this may not work if the latest version of a dependency still does not comply with this rule.

Answer (score 1):

In this error, majorly the fault is either for exported flag or for not using proper name in manifest.

For example,
if service is defined in your manifest, and you are declaring the process, then you have to define entire path i.e.

```
<service
        android:name=".ui.service.YOUR_SERVICE_NAME"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:process="com.example.ui.service.YOUR_SERVICE_NAME"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="ACTION_ACCEPT" />
            <action android:name="ACTION_REJECT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

As shown above,
It will give this error if used as follow:

```
android:process="YOUR_SERVICE_NAME"
```

instead try using as follow

```
android:process="com.example.ui.service.YOUR_SERVICE_NAME"
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to add .9.png files to your app , you need to define your xml file source in your main activity meta-data part as an android resource , this solved my problem:

```
     <meta-data
               android:name="com.google.android.actions
       //add this line
               android:resource="@drawable/sample_button 
       //(here sample_button is the name of your xml file in the drawable folder)"
        />
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by setting the target version to android 9 instead of android 13

I also used the `android:exported="true"` fix aswell

fixed it and install perfectly using adb on an samsung galaxy tab (running android 13)