# "Failed to finalize session : INSTALL_FAILED_USER_RESTRICTED: Invalid apk."

Tags: android, android-studio, installation

I am trying to install my app in mobile through android studio. It perfectly worked earlier but now it is returning this error

> Failed to finalize session : INSTALL_FAILED_USER_RESTRICTED: Invalid apk.

How to resolve this error?

[image]

Comment: While installing, watch out to mobile it would be asking for some permission to install that app, click allow at that time.

Comment: Thanks @GhulamMoinulQuadir for reverting, Yes I do used to see the permission pop-up but once I missed my chance of clicking on "Allow" and since then I am seeing this error

Comment: may be you installed an apk with same package but different version,t

Answer (score 0):

I found my error and resolved it!
In manifest file inside metadata element I had not mentioned valid value, by adding a value parameter the error got resolved. 
[You will find detailed description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26722908/7740770)

```
`<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"package="com.example.cognoscenti.interact">

<!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".RegisterActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name=".ProfileActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_profile"
        android:parentActivityName=".LoginActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.cognoscenti.interact.LoginActivity" />
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="Replace_Me"
        tools:replace="android:value"/>

    <provider
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
        android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider1620914054661826"
        android:exported="true" />

    <activity android:name=".AuthenticationActivity"></activity>
</application>
```

`