# Application Installation failed error [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED]

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am developing a application that implement the samsung myknox basic functionality. But I'm getting the below error while i'm trying to run the code.

Installation error: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED

I tried these links :

[Installation error: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6056564/installation-error-install-parse-failed-manifest-malformed)

[How to fix INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED in my android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12396351/how-to-fix-install-parse-failed-manifest-malformed-in-my-android-application)

[Android Studio : INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21716933/android-studio-install-parse-failed-manifest-malformed)

[Screen shot of error which i'm getting at time of run the application.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UjRJx.png)

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.sec.MDM_HW_CONTROL" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.sec.MDM_APP_MGMT" />

<application
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity
        android:name="com.signity.myknox.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver
        android:name="com.signity.myknox.SampleAdmin"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN">
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.device_admin" />
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver
        android:name="com.signity.myknox.SampleLicenseReceiver"
        android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="edm.intent.action.license.status" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> <meta-data android:name="android.app.device_admin" />
> ```

`meta-data` elements must have also a `value` or `resource` attribute, not just `name`.